# How to edit a model in sculpt mode

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, sculpting

I am trying to edit a model in sculpt mode to make the legs thicker. I was told to use the the inflate tool in sculpt mode but when I tried using it nothing happen. Why am I having this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add more geometry to your mesh or to enable the DYNOTOPO settings (so while you sculpt, you add more geometry automatically).

DYNOTOPO is under the ACTIVE TOOL settings (close to BRUSH SETTINGS)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The move tool works as well. I think you just need to keep looking for a spot on the mesh to get the brush to work possibly because of how your object is aligned for blender to read it.